# Prove that $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz

Tags: functions

I want to prove that a function $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a Lipschitz function.

I proved that $|\phi(x_1,C_1) - \phi(x_2,C_1)| \leq A |x_1 - x_2|$ and $|\phi(C_2,y_1) - \phi(C_2,y_2)| \leq A |y_1 - y_2|$, with $C_1$ and $C_2$ constant.
But I don't know how I should combine these two results to become $|\phi(x_1,y_1) - \phi(x_2,y_2)| \leq A |(x_1,y_1) - (x_2,y_2)|$.

Comment: define $\phi$.?

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
|\phi(x_1,y_1)-\phi(x_2,y_2)|&=|\phi(x_1,y_1)-\phi(x_1,y_2)+\phi(x_1,y_2)-\phi(x_2,y_2)|\\
&\le|\phi(x_1,y_1)-\phi(x_1,y_2)|+|\phi(x_1,y_2)-\phi(x_2,y_2)|\\
&\le A(|y_1-y_2|+|+|x_1-x_2|).
\end{align*}